# Настройка веб-сервера на VPS

Tags: vps

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть VPS (ubuntu 14), поставил на него apache. mysql, php.

Захожу по внешнему адресу (31.220.x.x).который предоставил хостер - страница не доступна/
По идее клиент должен на 80 порт стучаться по умолчанию, на котором установился apache. Как можно проверить порты или открыть их для доступа к серверу из вне(интернет)

Comment: пустая страница - это уже ответ, скорее всего php падает с ошибкой, а error reporting / display errors отключен. Проверить вы можете команндой `netstat -an | grep :80`.

Comment: Извиняюсь н пустая страница, а нет подключения

Comment: Поправьте вопрос и добавьте информацию

Comment: я до сих пор плаваю в этом вопросе, но, кажется, апач слушает **только** ipv6, а вы заходите по ipv4

Comment: а как зайти по ip4 ?

Comment: Автор, чтобы не разводить дискуссию, давайте доступ, я всё посмотрю и исправлю. В вопросе отпишу в чем было дело...

Comment: я бы не рекомендовал.

Comment: Чтобы вы не рекомендовали

Answer (score 1):

На сервере сделайте `netstat -anp | grep tcp`. Эта команда выдаст список портов, открытых для подключения. Но открытый порт на стороне сервера не означает его доступность для интернета...

Пустая страница в ответе сервера скорее всего сформирована уже apache.

Чтобы проверить то это или нет, разместите файл с именем `test` и содержимым `test` в дирректорию `/var/www` и откройте http://31.220.x.x/test. Если на странице будет надпись `test`, то это apache и 80 порт доступен извне.

Вообще администрирование VPS серверов достаточно важная часть владения сервером. Неверная установка может превратить проект в ничто... Воспользуйтесь услугами профессионалов.

Как и говорили в комментариях - apache слушает 80 порт только на ipv6. В конфиге указал `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` всё стало слушаться на ipv4.

**НО**

Подключение VPS к инету идет через интерфейс:

```
venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      inet addr:10.2**.**.**  P-t-P:10.2**.**.**  Bcast:10.2**.**.**  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Собственно пакеты просто не ходят...

**UPD**

Шайтан! VPS взята на бесплатный тест. Подключена через DNAT. Порты подменяются)

Оказалось, что нужный порт не 80, как написано в системе, а 8010. Очевидно то, что DNAT сделан с изменение портов.

*Вопрос можно закрывать)*

Comment: не пустая страница, а нет подключения

Comment: `Захожу по внешнему адресу (31.220.x.x).который предоставил хостер - пустая страница/` Приведите вывод `netstat -anp | grep tcp`, тогда можно продолжать.

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      717/apache2

Comment: картинка вначале поста

Comment: положил index.html в директорию var/www/ - тот же результат  - страница не  доступна

Comment: Порт может быть закрыт при помощи iptables.

Comment: Что это значит и что делать?

Comment: чтобы проверить догадку про iptables нужно выполнить `iptables -L`